# Conditional Formatting based on date and another cells data

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Struggling with some conditional formatting and I really don't understand why as it's something I've done numerous times before.

I have dates in Column F I need these to change if 6-11 months has passed, and a different colour for 11 months or more has passed

ONLY IF column U is equal to "specific text"

For some reason I can't get it to play how it should.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom rule applying to `=$F:$F`
with the following formula: `=AND(TODAY()-F1>182.5,TODAY()-F1<334.8,U1="specific text")`.

*It's not exactly 6 or 11 months* on a calendar, but it's corresponding percentages of the year. I chose 182.6 days and 334.8 days (365.25 divided by 2 and 365.25 * 11/12).

So all of the following need to be true:

- Today's date minus the date in the cell must be more than 182.6
- Today's date minus the date in the cell must be less than 334.8
- The corresponding U cell must match the text.

[image]

Then create a second rule and just use the same format without the second AND clause and tweaked for the right days.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this one.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula to highlight Dates, when 6 -11 months has been passed.

  ```
  =AND(H33>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+6,DAY(TODAY())),H33<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+11,DAY(TODAY())),I33="A")
  ```
- Formula to highlight Dates, when 11 months or more has been passed.

  ```
  =AND($H33>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+11,DAY(TODAY())),$I33="A")
  ```

**N.B.**

- The base date to compare is, `Current date`.
- You may edit the base date as well adjust cell references and the specific text in the formula, along with applied colors as needed.